# Sitecore Logged In Pipeline in Identity Server?

Tags: pipelines, authentication, federated-authentication, identity-server

I've created a Two Factor Authentication. It's working by adding our custom processor before **Sitecore.Pipelines.LoggedIn.Ticket**. But now in 9.1 with Identity Server, it won't be triggered unless I disabled Identity Server.

Do you guys have a workaround to add 2FA within Identity Server, or at least interfere login process within Identity Server?
Thanks

Comment: Sitecore 9.1 uses owin authentication, so look at .\Website\App_Config\Sitecore\Owin.Authentication. It contains the sign in and other related processors like <owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn help="Processors should derive from Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.CookieAuthentication.SignedIn.SignedInProcessor">

Comment: After trying to investigate what you @Gobinath said and then found this answer https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/17915/4774, I think I figured out how to make these things works. Thanks. I'm gonna write the answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured out the answer based on the comment from @Gobinath and answer of [this thread.](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/17915/4774)

So, first you must add NEW config for these Owin and IdentityServer stuffs and don't touch your previous version of these processes (before IdentityServer, in my case it's working properly without **IS**)

```
<configuration>
<sitecore>
<pipelines>

<owin.cookieAuthentication.signIn>
<processor resolve="true" type="your.SIGN-IN.pipeline, YourDLL" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.CookieAuthentication.SignIn.UpdateUserProperties, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication']"/>
</owin.cookieAuthentication.signIn>

<owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>
<processor resolve="true" type=" your.SIGNED-IN.Pipeline, YourDll" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.CookieAuthentication.SignedIn.CreateTicket, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication']"/>
</owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>

</pipelines>
</sitecore>
</configuration>
```

You can adjust patch:after processor and add more processors for your needs.

Then, on your code you need to inherit SignInProcessor or SignedInProcessor then override Process with SignInArgs/SignedInArgs as parameter.

```
public class YourSignInProcessor : SignInProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(SignInArgs args)
        {
          add your code here
        }
    }
public class YourSignedInProcessor : SignedInProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(SignedInArgs args)
        {
          add your code here
        }
    }
```

Since our code use Persist checking (LoggedInArgs.Persist (bool)), I'm not sure where is this persist checking located within SignedInArgs. I just commented out those lines for now. As Sitecore [said](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/understanding-sitecore-authentication-behavior-changes.html#UUID-153eb49e-9b9c-c95e-1e0c-c368778c900d_section-idm45403308284384_body)

> Web applications create persistent authentication cookies when a user
>   selects a Remember me option. Authentication through Federated
>   Authentication produces only non-persistent cookies.
>
> For example, if you sign in through an external identity provider
>   without selecting the Remember me option on that provider, then you
>   have to sign in again after the  browser session expires.
>
> If you sign in through an external identity provider and you select
>   the Remember me option on that provider, then you will lose your
>   Sitecore authentication cookie when the  browser session expires. 
>   However, after a quick auto-redirect to the identity provider and
>   back, you are automatically signed-in to Sitecore again.