# How to rework LoggingIn pipelines in Sitecore 9.1?

Tags: pipelines, authentication, migration

In **Sitecore 8.2**, I had pipeline with password complexity check:

```
public class CheckPassword
{
    public void Process(LoggingInArgs args)
    {
        var validator = new CustomValidator();
        if(!validator.Validate(args.UserName, args.Password))
        {
            args.StartUrl = "change password url";
        }
}
```

Sitecore 9.1 uses `OWIN` authentication and as i got it doesn't use this pipeline.

So, is it possible to get check credentials of user before they will be logged in?

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore uses Owin authentication, so you could probably do similar thing by using this "`owin.cookieAuthentication.signIn`" pipeline instead of "`loggingin`" pipeline

The config file is located at `App_Config\Sitecore\Owin.Authentication\Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.config`

Your patch could look something like this...

```
<owin.cookieAuthentication.signIn>
        <processor resolve="true" type="Namespace.CheckPassword, AssemblyName" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.CookieAuthentication.SignIn.RemoveTicket, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication']" />
</owin.cookieAuthentication.signIn>
```

Your codes could be something like this (I have not tested this)

```
public class CheckPassword : SignInProcessor
{
    public void Process(SignInArgs args)
    {
        var validator = new CustomValidator();
        if(!validator.Validate(args))
        {
            args.Success = false;
            args.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("change password url");
            args.AbortPipeline();
        }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, added more information in question. Previously i was able to validate credentials with membership provider. SignInArgs class doesn't have Password of the user, so I am not able to validate credentials

Comment: I didn't found any suitable owin pipelines for this purpose. Alternatively you might consider disabling identity server https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/understanding-sitecore-authentication-behavior-changes.html#UUID-153eb49e-9b9c-c95e-1e0c-c368778c900d_section-idm45851236122672

Comment: I decided to avoid this pipeline at all. Custom MembershipProvider will use same validator and it is possible to force users to change password once, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on this one and did get some pointers to debug my work further, like you I was struggling to add pipeline hooks at correct location. Found the answer in [this](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17786/sitecore-logged-in-pipeline-in-identity-server) SO question.

I had tried two actions, on successful SignIn and once SignedIn, unfortunately both are triggering on initial login and I am trying to find answer to trigger on auto login via cookie or just refresh of page. Happy searching....

Here is my patch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <owin.cookieAuthentication.signIn>
        <processor resolve="true" type="CMS.Logging.CheckOnSignIn, CMS" 
                   patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.CookieAuthentication.SignIn.UpdateUserProperties, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication']" />
      </owin.cookieAuthentication.signIn>
      <owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>
        <processor resolve="true" type="CMS.Logging.CheckOnSignedIn, CMS"
                   patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.CookieAuthentication.SignedIn.CreateTicket, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication']" />
      </owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```